# system.net.mail.smtpException :Unable to connect to the remote server?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I am trying to send email using Kinghost SMTP but I have the following error:

`system.net.mail.smtpException : failure sending mail`

Any ideas why?

```
 private bool SendEmail( string sendto, string sendfrom, string subject, string body )
        {
            bool status = false;
            try
            {
                msg.To.Clear();
                clint.Host = "smtp.kinghost.net";
                clint.Port = 25;
                clint.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                clint.Credentials = smtpCrede;
                clint.EnableSsl = true;
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(sendto);
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sendfrom);
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = body;
                msg.From = from;
                msg.To.Add(to);
                clint.Send(msg);
                status = true;
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            return status;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is probably blocking outbound connecctions on port 25.

Try port 587.

Comment: i have add port 25 in firewall . if i use 587 then exception is transaction frailer.

Comment: Your **ISP** is probably blocking port 25, regardless of your firewall (ask them).  Contact your host and ask them what ports they accept.